# Unable to retrieve SubIFD for a dng image in MATLAB

Tags: android, matlab, image-processing

I have a digital negative which I am trying to read into Matlab and process it. I used the following 3 lines to read it for now.

```
filename='imagename.dng';
t=Tiff(filename,'r');
offsets = getTag(t,'SubIFD');
```

The warnings and errors that I get are as follows

```
 raw2display
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 33421 (0x828d) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 33422 (0x828e) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 33434 (0x829a) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 33437 (0x829d) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 34855 (0x8827) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 36867 (0x9003) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 37386 (0x920a) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 37398 (0x9216) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 50964 (0xc714) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 50965 (0xc715) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 51009 (0xc741) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 51022 (0xc74e) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library warning - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Unknown
field with tag 51041 (0xc761) encountered.' 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Warning: TIFF library error - '_TIFFVSetField:
/Users/bryan/Documents/Project/img_0531/IMG_20160531_105331.dng:
Bad value 0 for "Orientation" tag.' - file may be corrupt. 
> In Tiff (line 651)
  In raw2display (line 4) 
Error using tifflib
Unable to retrieve SubIFD.

Error in Tiff/getTag (line 838)
                    tagValue =
                    tifflib('getField',obj.FileID,Tiff.TagID.(tagId));

Error in raw2display (line 5)
offsets = getTag(t,'SubIFD');
```

The imfinfo for the image gives me the following output

`Filename: ''
                  FileModDate: '31-May-2016 13:53:32'
                     FileSize: 24738008
                       Format: 'tif'
                FormatVersion: []
                        Width: 4080
                       Height: 3028
                     BitDepth: 16
                    ColorType: 'CFA'
              FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                    ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
               NewSubFileType: 0
                BitsPerSample: 16
                  Compression: 'Uncompressed'
    PhotometricInterpretation: 'CFA'
                 StripOffsets: [1x3028 double]
              SamplesPerPixel: 1
                 RowsPerStrip: 1
              StripByteCounts: [1x3028 double]
                  XResolution: 72
                  YResolution: 72
               ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                     Colormap: []
          PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                    TileWidth: []
                   TileLength: []
                  TileOffsets: []
               TileByteCounts: []
                  Orientation: 0
                    FillOrder: 1
             GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
               MaxSampleValue: 65535
               MinSampleValue: 0
                 Thresholding: 1
                       Offset: 8
             ImageDescription: ''
                         Make: 'LGE'
                        Model: 'Nexus 5X'
                     Software: 'google/bullhead/bullhe…'
                     DateTime: '2016:05:27 06:33:52'
                    Copyright: ''
                 ExposureTime: 1.9983e-04
                      FNumber: 2
              ISOSpeedRatings: 80
             DateTimeOriginal: '2016:05:27 06:33:52'
                  FocalLength: 4.6700
                   DNGVersion: [1 4 0 0]
           DNGBackwardVersion: [1 1 0 0]
            UniqueCameraModel: 'Nexus 5X-LGE-google'
                CFAPlaneColor: [0 1 2]
                    CFALayout: 1
          BlackLevelRepeatDim: [2 2]
                   BlackLevel: [52 52 52 52]
                   WhiteLevel: 1023
                 DefaultScale: [1 1]
            DefaultCropOrigin: [8 8]
              DefaultCropSize: [4016 3008]
                 ColorMatrix1: [1x9 double]
                 ColorMatrix2: [1x9 double]
           CameraCalibration1: [1x9 double]
           CameraCalibration2: [1x9 double]
                AsShotNeutral: [0.5312 1 0.4062]
       CalibrationIlluminant1: 21
       CalibrationIlluminant2: 17
                   ActiveArea: [2 48 3026 4080]
                  UnknownTags: [8x1 struct]`

This image was clicked using a Nexus 5x device running the app Android L Camera. Also I notice that there is no LinearizationTable here. Can you help me fix this or give me more information about it?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, try using first "Adobe DNG converter":
http://supportdownloads.adobe.com/product.jsp?product=106&platform=Windows
After that, try running the code on the processed image. The mosaic image will be stored in the variable "cfa" in B&W

```
clear all;
close all;
warning off MATLAB:tifflib:TIFFReadDirectory:libraryWarning
t = Tiff('DSC_9511_conv.dng','r');
offsets = getTag(t,'SubIFD');
setSubDirectory(t,offsets(1));
cfa = read(t);
close(t);
```